# Facebook Deffered Deep Linking with FB Unity3D SDK setup

Tags: android, ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, sdk

so i made a game using Unity 5.2 with integrating FB SDK with it

i already made the app page, and already done integrating it on my android/iOS app, everything done quite well

now i want to use Facebook ads to boost my game even further

i go to this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/sdk , to verify if my game ready for ads setup

and i got this problem :

Problem Image

[image]

i honestly don't know anything about defered deep link, i already tried googling and youtube but still found nothing

the documentation on Android : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AppLinkData/#fetchDeferredAppLinkData

and iOS : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKAppLinkUtility/#fetchDeferredAppLink

didnt help at all,

even when i search about it for FB unity SDK, i only ended up on this documentation page : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.GetAppLink
which didn't explain anything about deeplink...

i already made the app.me facebook link for my app, and already use it on share feature on my app, but still it didn't count as defered deep link, which is very confuse me

i stuck here about couple days now, if anyone know regarding this, please enlighten me

thank you in advance :)

** after post it on facebook developer group, it seems no one know either, or didn't bother to help, still stuck till today :(

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: iam sorry, iam not, i just said screw it and dont use it at this point for now

Answer (score 0):

for android I followed this documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android

and here is for iOS
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios